# Uncaught exception in appdelegate swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, exception, app-store

How do I handle all unhandled exceptions in application level?

I tried with `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` and it called only for NSExceptions.

I would like to handle uncaught exceptions in app level and allow users to continue with app without any crashes by navigating to home (some)page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use try catch block in your code. It will help to prevent the crashes in your application.

```
do {
    try {
    // do something here
    // if the call fails, the catch block is executed
}
} catch {
    //do something when catch block executes.
}
```